# Could not build Objective-C module 'Alamofire' Xcode 10.3

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, cocoapods, alamofire

I want to use alamofire for my xcode project but got an error:

[Could not build Objective-C module 'Alamofire'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gobg0.png)

Here is my pod file:
[pod file image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSruN.png)

Comment: If you're using the Xcode 10.3, use Alamofire 4.9.1 or lower.

Comment: use AFNetworking for objective c projects. pod 'AFNetworking'

Comment: Update your XCode